# Java, putting all datatypes in one array

Tags: java, networking, message

I work on project that involves client-server communication and they communicate using messages. But because there are different types of messages i decided to create a class called Message.

```
public class Message {
    private String   m_MessageType;
    private Object[] m_Arguments;

    public Message() {

    }

    // Have this constructor to quick add arguments to message
    // instead calling Add method for every single argument
    public Message( String aMessageType, Object... aArguments ) {
        // do something
    }

    // These methods allow to add data to message at the and of array/list
    public void Add(int i) {}
    public void Add(float f) {}
    public void Add(String s) {}
    // ... and so on for all datatypes in Java

    // Get methods allow to retrieve data at the specific index of array/list
    public int GetInteger(int index) {
        return (int) m_Arguments[index];
    }

    public String GetString(int index) {
        return (String) m_Arguments[index];
    }
    // ... and so on for all datatypes in Java

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // return String representation of message
    }
}
```

On client and server side I have MessageHandlers which are registered by type of the message and are executed on recieved message.
In this aproach I have problem because primitive dataypes in Java are not objects and since that i cannot cast them in object or from object to primitive datatype. Is there any way I can acomplish this and does this have some name or something like design pattern...

I could use Integer, Double,... classes but that would require to send more bytes over network because Integer class costs more bytes than primitive datatype and I kinda don't want to send that much of bytes. I would like to keep message size as lower as possible...

EDIT: I forgot to mention, there are multiple clients and one server...

Comment: Note: `@Override
    public void toString() {}` won't compile. It should be  `@Override
    public String toString() {}`

Comment: Yeah, you right. Thanks for pointing that out, I was typing code directly not pasteing it from project...

Comment: Also method names should start with lowercase. Anyway I think you're optimizing too early. I'd go with boxed datatypes and optimize based on some real traffic if needed. If you'll be passing primitives, you will still need to know what types they are(how can you tell that 0 is int, long, double or that the value is not provided at all?).

Comment: I think you are stuck using the primitive wrappers, unless you want to re-engineer things a bit.  The first thing that came to my mind would be to use generic collections instead of an array of Objects on the arguments property.  It won't solve your issue of using wrapper classes, though.  You could refactor the `Message` so that `Message` is an abstract class, and then you extend it to make `Message` sub-classes that handle primitives in a more specific way.  How are you sending the messages, JMX, raw Sockets, or some other way (Web Service, perhaps?)?

Comment: Can you implement [java.io.Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html)?

Comment: Why not just use an array of Object and use String, Integer, and Float objects?  The data you transmit is not tied to the local representation -- it just needs to be a defined protocol.  (In fact, you probably should be using JSON -- an array of Strings and Numbers will serialize to JSON very naturally.)

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I have MessageHandlers which knows how datatypes are stored in Array. For example if I send message: {TYPE_CHAT_MESSAGE, "clzola", "hello"} handler that handles this type of message will do GetString method twice because it knows that first arguments is sender and the second argument is text of message.

Comment: @CodeChimp I am using Socket class. I tried that method with creating abstract class Message and than derive other message types but there is a lot of type of messages and the list is not final, so I wanted this aproach to implement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can directly store the data as byte[] in that way u can convert all primitive data types to Byte in java easily see  [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

instead of
       private Object[] m_Arguments;

can use
        private byte[][] m_Arguments;

or
       private ByteBuffer[] m_Arguments;

Comment: I'll give you +1, if you also explain how you put an object into the ByteBuffer.

Comment: How are u creating the object? cast the object using appropriate class and then convert it to byte array

Comment: With this approach, you will need some way to store how to deserialize the data, as you wont know on the other end if the given byte array is an int, float, double, etc.  You may end up sending more across the wire than if you simply stuck with the wrapper classes, but that greatly depends on implementation.  Have you considered a different strategy for serializing the data, like perhaps JSON or XML?

Comment: For the object type to be known in the other side and data to be transfered as byte, type of data has to be embedded and sent along with the data this approach will require size of data also to be embedded. JSON or XML is a gud options as told by @CodeChimp